# WPF Binding 3 collections together

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I hane a MVVM app where I'd like to bind 3 collections together. In View I have ItemsControl with TimeBoxes (Just TextBoxes with dependency property Time).

```
<Window x:Class="Scoreboard.View.MainWindow"
    ...
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TimeBoxes}"/>
    ...
</Window>
```

With code behind

```
public class Mainwindow
{
    //...
    var Timeboxes = new ObservableCollection<TimeBox>();
}
```

In model I would like to have a Time collection.

```
public class GameModel
{
    var Times = new ObservableCollection<Time>();
    // Don't know if this is how it should be
}
```

And then I have another window with ouput which is similiar to Views MainWindow, but ItemsControl holds Borders instead of TimeBoxes.

```
<Window x:Class="Scoreboard.Display.DisplayWindow"
    ...
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Borders}"/>
    ...
</Window>
```

What it should do is: Upon clicking on a button in View (`MainWindow`) a `TimeBox` is created in `TimeBoxes` collection. `Time` of that `TimeBox` is bound to a new `Time` in `Times` in `GameModel`. And that `Time` is also bound to content (label) of a new `Border` (I have `TimeToStringConverter` for this) in the `Borders` of the output (display) `Window`. When a `Time` in `GameModel` reaches zero, its instances are removed from all collections. My problem is I don't know how to bind an item in a collection to an item of another collection. ViewModel is omitted for simplicity.

To summarize I want to dynamically bind a `TimeBox` to `Time` and that `Time` to `Border`'s content in 1:1:1 ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a tested solution for a `CollectionHelper` that binds 2 `ObservableCollection` together. When an item is added or removed from one collection, the other is updated.
The `Bind` method returns an `IDisposable`, so when you dispose it, the automatic update is terminated.
This works with 2 collection of the same generic type. If you need a method to handle collection of different types, you should implement a method with a signature like the commented method:

```
[TestClass]
public class BindTwoObservableCollections_test
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void BindTwoObservableCollections()
    {
        var c1 = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        var c2 = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        c1.Add(1);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, c2.Count);

        var subscription = CollectionHelper.Bind(c1, c2);

        c1.Add(2);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, c2.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, c2[0]);

        c2.Add(3);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, c1.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, c1[2]);

        c2.Remove(2);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, c1.Count);

        subscription.Dispose();

        c2.Remove(3);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, c1.Count);
    }
}

public static class CollectionHelper
{
    public static IDisposable Bind<T>(
        ObservableCollection<T> c1,
        ObservableCollection<T> c2)
    {
        var fromC1Subscription = InternalBind(c1, c2);
        var fromC2Subscription = InternalBind(c2, c1);

        return new Disposable(() =>
        {
            fromC1Subscription?.Dispose();
            fromC2Subscription?.Dispose();
        });
    }

    private static IDisposable InternalBind<T>(
        ObservableCollection<T> from,
        ObservableCollection<T> to)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler onFromChanged =
            (s, e) =>
            {
                switch (e.Action)
                {
                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                        foreach (T added in e.NewItems)
                            if (!to.Contains(added))
                                to.Add(added);
                        break;

                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                        foreach (T removed in e.OldItems)
                            to.Remove(removed);
                        break;

                    //other cases...

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            };

        from.CollectionChanged += onFromChanged;

        return new Disposable(() => { from.CollectionChanged -= onFromChanged; });
    }

    //public static IDisposable Bind<T1, T2>(
    //    ObservableCollection<T1> c1,
    //    ObservableCollection<T2> c2,
    //    Func<T1, T2> converter1,
    //    Func<T2, T1> converter2)
    //{
    //    todo...
    //}
}

public class Disposable : IDisposable
{
    public Disposable(Action onDispose)
    {
        _onDispose = onDispose;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _onDispose?.Invoke();
    }

    private Action _onDispose;
}
```

Obviously, if you need to bind c1, c2 and c3, you write:

```
CollectionHelper.Bind(c1, c2);
CollectionHelper.Bind(c2, c3);
```

And that's enough.

Comment: Thanks man, this is a sweet solution. I was so focused in binding that I forgot about Notifying :D

Comment: "I know that feel, bro" ;)